# How can I stop the numbering of equations in the align command

Tags: equations, numbering, align

With this code I have numbering of equations:

```
    \begin{align}
  U_{2} = - u_{2}(h) + x_{2},\label{eqn:foca1}\\
  Y_{2} = x_{2} + T,\label{eqn:focb1}\\
  u_{1}(h) + T \geq u_{1}(h^*) .\label{eqn:focc1}
\end{align}
```

I have tried align* but that didn't work. Are there any suggestions on how I can stop the numbering of equations in the align command?

Comment: Just add `\nonumber` before \\ in those lines you don't what to be numbered

Comment: @pablos Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: `\begin{align}
      U_{2} = - u_{2}(h) + x_{2},\label{eqn:foca1}\nonumber \\ %this line won't be numbered
    Y_{2} = x_{2} + T,\label{eqn:focb1}\\ %this line will be numbered
    u_{1}(h) + T \geq u_{1}(h^*) .\label{eqn:focc1}\nonumber    %this line won't be numbered
    \end{align}`

Comment: @pablos - Please provide this information in an *answer* rather than in a *comment*.

Comment: There's not a single alignment point (`&`) in the `align` environment. As a result, the three rows are set ragged-left. Is that your intention? If the three rows are supposed to be aligned on the `=` and `\geq` symbols, the symbols should get an `&` prefix. If the three rows are supposed to be individually centered, use a `gather` (or gather*`) environment instead of an `align` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `align*` there are error messages because of the `\label` commands:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'eqn:foca1' will be lost
```

`\label` does not make much sense without numbering anyway, thus removing them
gets `align*` work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align*}
    U_{2} = - u_{2}(h) + x_{2},\\
    Y_{2} = x_{2} + T,\\
    u_{1}(h) + T \geq u_{1}(h^*) .
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result align*]

If some equations should be numbered and others should not get a number, then `\notag` (or `\nonumber`) can be used to suppress the equation number (see also [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202647/how-can-i-stop-the-numbering-of-equations-in-the-align-command/202651#comment472620_202647) of pablos):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    U_{2} = - u_{2}(h) + x_{2},\notag\\
    Y_{2} = x_{2} + T,\notag\\
    u_{1}(h) + T \geq u_{1}(h^*) .\label{eqn:foc}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result align with \notag]

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{align} 
U_{2} = - u_{2}(h) + x_{2},\label{eqn:foca1}\nonumber \\ %this line won't be numbered 
Y_{2} = x_{2} + T,\label{eqn:focb1}\\ %this line will be numbered 
u_{1}(h) + T \geq u_{1}(h^*) .\label{eqn:focc1}\nonumber %this line won't be numbered 
\end{align}
```

Comment: Please add some to text to explain why this helps to solve the problem.